# How to read xlsx file with ExcelJS?

Tags: javascript, xlsx, xls, exceljs

How does the code should look like to get cell A1 value from the file "C:\1.xlsx"? I tried numbers of examples but still didn't managed to get it work.

```
var Excel = require('exceljs');

var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();

workbook.xlsx.readFile("C:\1.xlsx")
    .then(function() {
        var worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet('Sheet1');
        var cell = worksheet.getCell('A1').value;
        console.log(cell);
    });
```

I see no errors, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried `worksheet.getCell('A1')` ? See the [Readme](https://github.com/guyonroche/exceljs#handling-individual-cells)

Comment: @R. Schifini, yes I tried.

Comment: Have you tried getting the worksheet first and then the cell from that worksheet? `worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet('My Sheet')` => `woksheet.getCell('A1').value`

Comment: Change "c:\1.xlsx" to "c:/1.xlsx". The \ is an escape character.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to access the worksheet first and then the cell. Like this:

```
var Excel = require('exceljs');
var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
workbook.xlsx.readFile("C:/1.xlsx")
    .then(function() {
        ws = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet1")
        cell = ws.getCell('A1').value
        console.log(cell)
    });
```

Replace "Sheet1" with the real sheet's name. You can also access the worksheet by id.

```
ws = workbook.getWorksheet(1)
```

Comment: thank you. I made the same a few seconds before your answer and updated my post. It's not working.

Comment: @F.Vosnim you have a problem with "c:\1.xlsx".  The `\\` is an escape character. Change it to /. You are not reading the file.

Comment: Try "c:\\1.xlsx".

Comment: `c:\\1.xlsx` and `c:\/1.xlsx` don't work. With no errors.

Comment: I can't help you further, my code worked in my computer.

Comment: R. Schifini, thank you for your help. I'm not sure how it works, but when I placed your code inside await it started to work.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to use `getCell().value`, like:

```
var cell = worksheet.getCell('C3').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
await (new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var Excel = require('exceljs');
    var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
    workbook.xlsx.readFile("C:/1.xlsx")
        .then(function() {
            ws = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet1")
            cell = ws.getCell('A1').value
            console.log(cell)
            resolve()
        });
}));
```